# Indicator function of an infinitesimal set

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

While reading a paper related to functional of brownian motion I came across the following notation $1(B_t \in dx)$, where $1(A)$ is the indicator function of the set A, and $B_t$ is a standard brownian motion.

...Trying to make sense of the expectation of this random variable I write informally:
$$E[1(B_t \in dx)]=\int_R 1(X_t \in dx)f_{X_t}(x)dx=\int_{a}^{a+dx}f_{X_t}(x)dx=f_{X_t}(a)dx$$
with $f_{X_t}(x)dx$ the density function of std brownian motion at time t. I have no doubt in my mind that the last 2 equalities makes little sense, but I can't really figure what it should be instead.

Appreciate any pointers, thanks.

Comment: Erm what is Xt, a and R? I think it is correct except there might be typos or unexplained notations

Comment: Which paper? // Are you sure this was $1(B_t\in dx)$ and not $P(B_t\in dx)$?

Comment: Xt is my Brownian motion, no different from Bt, just a notation looseness on my part, R is the Real line, and a is any point on that line. The paper it is extracted from is called "The Feynman Kac formula and pricing occupation time derivatives". Yes it is an indicator RV , not the probability measure.